# Join multiple lines

Tags: line-breaks

I have a file similar to this:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccccccccccc
dddddddddddddddddddd


aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccccccccccc
dddddddddddddddddddd


aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccccccccccc
dddddddddddddddddddd
```

I would like to join them to this:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
```

Until now I have done this by selecting blocks in (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>) and deleting them (<kbd>x</kbd>) and pasting them to the end of the first block (<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>). This is very time consuming and I did not manage to get these things working in a macro.

*How can I combine multiple blocks of lines?*

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760326/merge-multiple-lines-two-blocks-in-vim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the macro working:

```
qqgg5j^V4j$xgg$p9jV4kd
```

- `qq` starts a macro called `q`
- `gg` sets the startingpoint to the first line of the file
- `5j` goes down 5 lines (the start of the block below it)
- `^V4j$` goes into column selection mode and selects the first block
- `x`  cut the content of the selection
- `gg$p` paste it to the end of the first block
- `9jV4kd` delete the empty lines left after cutting

Typing in `2@q` performs this action twice combining all lines

Comment: You could perhaps simplify the macro by deleting the empty lines before starting it: `:g/^$/d`, or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

Another macro solution:

- First go to the beginning of the first paragraph (in your example with `10G`)
- Then record macro: <kbd>qq</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-Shit-V</kbd><kbd>}</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>
- Reuse the macro with <kbd>@q</kbd>

The detail of the macro:

- <kbd>Ctrl-Shit-V</kbd> start visual block mode
- <kbd>}</kbd> select to the last line of the paragraph
- <kbd>$</kbd> select to the end of the line
- <kbd>d</kbd> delete the selection
- <kbd>5k</kbd> go to the first line of the previous paragraph
- <kbd>$</kbd> got to the end of this line
- <kbd>p</kbd> past the previously deleted paragraph
- <kbd>0</kbd> go to the beginning of the line to be able to repeat the macro

Answer (score 3):

What you do is almost .. graphical, so I'd use the mouse!

(of course you need `:set mouse+=a`)

Select a block with the mouse, then `Ctrl-v` `y` to yank the selection in "control-block" mode (<- that's the "secret" sauce). Still using the mouse, place cursor on top right character of the 2nd block. Paste (`p`).

Repeat :D ... That's all!

Yes, it's probably not feasible for a macro, or a large number of repetitions, but how long a line do you want to make?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way:

Make sure the `a` register is empty

```
:let @a = ''
```

Match all lines starting with `aa`, and then append them to the `a` register with `y` (the capital `A` means append, rather than overwrite). After that delete the line with `d`.

```
:g/^aa/y A | d
```

Now we can paste this at the start of the buffer (or anywhere else you'd like):

```
1G"aP
```

And join them:

```
4gJ
```

Repeat for `bbb`, `ccc`, etc.

The last step is perhaps easier done as:

```
vnnngJ
```

Which starts visual mode with `v`, `n` to skip past the lines, and then `J` to join them. You could also press `J` a few times in a row...

or:

```
v/^bbb<Enter>kgJ
```

Which searches for `/^bbb`, this has the advantage that the last used search pattern is now "primed" for our next `:g` invocation, which can now read:

```
:g//y A | d
```

Not specifying a pattern will use the last used search pattern (i.e. the `@/` register).

Comment: You could use `gJ` instead of `J` to prevent Vim from inserting spaces.

Comment: @JairLopez Ah yes, I forgot about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The interesting thing is how to deal with movement. 
If the lines to join start with same characters you can do (automated with a macro):

```
qq*"aD''*"AD''$"apj0
```

where:

1. <kbd><kbd>`q`</kbd><kbd>`q`</kbd></kbd> record a macro
2. <kbd><kbd>`*`</kbd><kbd>`"`</kbd><kbd>`a`</kbd><kbd>`D`</kbd><kbd>`'`</kbd><kbd>`'`</kbd></kbd>  move to the line whith next char like first char of the first line, put the line in the register "a" and delete
3. <kbd><kbd>`*`</kbd><kbd>`"`</kbd><kbd>`A`</kbd><kbd>`D`</kbd><kbd>`'`</kbd><kbd>`'`</kbd></kbd> like 2. but append the line to the register
4. <kbd><kbd>`$`</kbd><kbd>`"`</kbd><kbd>`a`</kbd><kbd>`p`</kbd></kbd> paste register "a" at the end of the first line
5. <kbd><kbd>`j`</kbd><kbd>`0`</kbd></kbd> move to the start of the next line

Then repeat the macro:

```
3@q
```

and delete the empty lines:

```
:$d
```